# node.js mysql query cannot run due to quotes around digit

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have this mysql query written in node.js mysql and restify to be executed in a HTTP GET. 
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

```
var api_get_func = function (app, url_path) {
    function respond(req, res, next) {
        var id= req.query.id;
        var limit = req.query.limit;   

    var query_str =
        "SELECT table.sw_type, " +
        "FROM users " +
        "WHERE (id = ?) " + 
        "LIMIT ?"; //limit

    var var_arr = [id, limit];  

    var query = connection.query(query_str, var_arr, function (err, rows, fields) {}
        //SQL query ...
        return next();
    }

app.get(url_path, respond);
}
```

The HTTP GET URL is `http://127.0.0.1/read_sw?id=51&limit=1`

The error reported is that the query is not properly formed. The actual query looks like this;

```
SELECT table.sw_type, 
            FROM users 
            WHERE (id = 51) 
            LIMIT '1'
```

I think the problem is `LIMIT '1'`. I think the solution is to make the query look like this;

```
SELECT table.sw_type, 
            FROM users 
            WHERE (id = 51) 
            LIMIT 1
```

How can the node.js code be modified?

Comment: You have 2 errors: the LIMIT is need to get number and not string. so do `var limit = Number(req.query.limit)`, and remove the comma after `table.sw_type`

Comment: just verify and change id and limit variable to number instead of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about mysql...

Anything in req.query is a string :

How about

```
var var_arr = [id, parseInt(limit)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
var limit = Number(req.query.limit);
```